# Find indexes of matching rows in two 2-D arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose that I have two 2-D arrays as follows:

```
array([[3, 3, 1, 0],
       [2, 3, 1, 3],
       [0, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 0, 2]], dtype=int8)

array([[0, 3, 3, 1],
       [0, 2, 3, 1],
       [1, 0, 2, 3],
       [3, 1, 0, 2],
       [3, 3, 1, 0]], dtype=int8)
```

Some rows in each array have a corresponding row that matches by value (but not necessarily by index) in the other array, and some don't.

I would like to find an efficient way to return pairs of indexes in the two arrays that correspond to matching rows. If they were to be tuples I would expect to return

```
(0,4)
(2,1)
(3,2)
(4,3)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an all `numpy` solution - not that is necessarily better than an iterative Python one.  It still has to look at all combinations.

```
In [53]: np.array(np.all((x[:,None,:]==y[None,:,:]),axis=-1).nonzero()).T.tolist()
Out[53]: [[0, 4], [2, 1], [3, 2], [4, 3]]
```

The intermediate array is `(5,5,4)`.  The `np.all` reduces it to:

```
array([[False, False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

The rest is just extracting the indices where this is `True`

In crude tests, this times at 47.8 us; the other answer with the `L1` dictionary at 38.3 us; and a third with a double loop at 496 us.

Answer (score 6):

I can't think of a numpy specific way to do it, but here's what I would do with regular lists:

```
>>> L1= [[3, 3, 1, 0],
...        [2, 3, 1, 3],
...        [0, 2, 3, 1],
...        [1, 0, 2, 3],
...        [3, 1, 0, 2]]
>>> L2 = [[0, 3, 3, 1],
...        [0, 2, 3, 1],
...        [1, 0, 2, 3],
...        [3, 1, 0, 2],
...        [3, 3, 1, 0]]
>>> L1 = {tuple(row):i for i,row in enumerate(L1)}
>>> answer = []
>>> for i,row in enumerate(L2):
...   if tuple(row) in L1:
...     answer.append((L1[tuple(row)], i))
... 
>>> answer
[(2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (0, 4)]
```

Comment: O(n)! Nice. But isn't there a numpy way to do it?

Comment: @slider: `I can't think of a numpy way to do it`, primarily because I don't use numpy as much (it's been on my todo list for longer than I'm proud to admit)

Comment: Could this be generalized for the case that `L2` has only one row, and we want to get 'row indices' of matching rows in `L1`, with the rows in `L1` not necessarily being unique?

Answer (score 6):

You can use the void data type trick to use 1D functions on the rows of your two arrays. `a_view` and `b_view` are 1D vectors, each entry representing a full row. I have then chosen to sort an array and use `np.searchsorted` to find the items of the other array in that one. If the array we sort has length `m` and the other has length `n`, sorting takes time `m * log(m)`, and the binary searching that `np.searchsorted` does takes time `n * log(m)`, for a total of `(n + m) * log(m)`. You therefore want to sort the shortest of the two arrays:

```
def find_rows(a, b):
    dt = np.dtype((np.void, a.dtype.itemsize * a.shape[1]))

    a_view = np.ascontiguousarray(a).view(dt).ravel()
    b_view = np.ascontiguousarray(b).view(dt).ravel()

    sort_b = np.argsort(b_view)
    where_in_b = np.searchsorted(b_view, a_view,
                                 sorter=sort_b)
    where_in_b = np.take(sort_b, where_in_b)
    which_in_a = np.take(b_view, where_in_b) == a_view
    where_in_b = where_in_b[which_in_a]
    which_in_a = np.nonzero(which_in_a)[0]
    return np.column_stack((which_in_a, where_in_b))
```

With `a` and `b` your two sample arrays:

```
In [14]: find_rows(a, b)
Out[14]: 
array([[0, 4],
       [2, 1],
       [3, 2],
       [4, 3]], dtype=int64)

In [15]: %timeit find_rows(a, b)
10000 loops, best of 3: 29.7 us per loop
```

On my system the dictionary approach clocks faster at about 22 us for your test data, but with arrays of 1000x4, this numpy approach is about 6x faster than the pure Python one (483 us vs 2.54 ms).

Comment: This is brilliant.  It took me a full hour to figure out what in the world you were doing.
Although there is a slight bug since searchsorted has the possibility of returning that the item should be inserted at the end which results in an index out of bounds error.

Comment: for an example just change the last row of the a array to [3,3,3,3] and you will get `IndexError: index 5 is out of bounds for size 5`

Comment: This really sped up my code, thanks so much. Using a dict() on the rows just couldn't cut it for 10^4 or more rows.