# Numpy: Find indexes of rows in another array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have two arrays containing lists of 3d coordinates.

I am trying to get a list of the indexes where each element in my array is found in another array.

```
a = np.array([[0.4,0.6,0.8],
              [0.4, 1.0, 1.2],
              [0.6,1.0,1.4],
              [0.6,1.2,1.6]])

b = np.array([[0.4, 1.0, 1.2],
              [0.4,0.6,0.8],
              [0.6,1.2,1.6],
              [0.6,1.0,1.4],
              [0.6,1.0,1.4]])

idx = [np.where(np.all(a==i,axis=1)) for i in b]
# idx = [1, 0, 3, 2, 2]
```

Is there a way to achieve this using numpy methods as my arrays for a and b are large ~100k elements each.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A list or list of lists? Can you provide sample output?

Comment: This help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20230384/find-indexes-of-matching-rows-in-two-2-d-arrays

Comment: MYousefi A list or list of lists are both acceptable I have added the expected output for idx as a comment

Answer (score 0):

You can use `b[:,None]` for the comparison. It is a special kind of slicing that allows you to compare both arrays row-wise, since the shape of `b` is now (5,1,3), instead of (5,3).

```
idx = np.where( (a==b[:,None]).all(-1) )[1]

#output of idx: [1 0 3 2 2]
```